# How to convert a given string to object in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, tostring

I want to convert a string to and Object and below is my code

```
$scope.myString = "{'profit': 2.276273727416992}";
$scope.result = angular.toJson($scope.myString);
console.log('is object = ' + angular.isObject($scope.result)); // false
```

I'm using `angular.toJson()` for conversion to but its not working out.
Please let me know what is wrong here and how can I convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `angular.fromJson` to deserialize a JSON string. ([link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson))

Moreover, json requires double quotes:

```
$scope.myString = "{\"profit\": 2.276273727416992}";
$scope.result = angular.fromJson($scope.myString);
console.log('is object = ' + angular.isObject($scope.result)); // true
```